# Why the website is showing 'The site is experiencing technical difficulties' error only in category pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

Whenever I click on a category from any of the pages or posts which are posted, to go to that category archives, it gives me this error instead of showing the posts of that category. It only shows the site header with the error. Most other pages working fine.

I'm not sure if that's what caused the problem, but as the site has a 'Members only' content plugin which shows some posts to only the signed in members of the site. Also, Yoast plugin has an option of making a category of a post as a 'Primary' category, and as the categories are sorted in alphabetical order, if for example, we chose cat-1 and cat-2 and made the cat-2 a Primary category, it would show cat-1 on the website if cat-1 is alphabetically sorted before cat-2 (for ex. Member and Technology, if even we chose Technology as Primary, Member will be shown on site, on original breadcrumb for ex.).

What I tried to do is to hide the actual breadcrumb and show the Yoast breadcrumb instead by following their instructions from their FAQ. It involves adding a small code, I added it before the actual breadcrumb code and commented the actual breadcrumb's code (which is only just
a function name that is called, but it disabled anyway). Then I enabled the breadcrumb option from Yoast's settings panel (Added small code about adding the breadcrumb).

It was working fine and shows the primary checked category first, but then when we enter the category archive page (by clicking on it from breadcrumb or menu dropdown, no difference), it shows that error. I disabled a few plugins and also used the Health Check plugin and did some troubleshooting with it with some plugins disabled, but no positive results.

I enabled debug mode to see what is the error, and this is what it shows:

- Above the header:

> Notice: is_author was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in .../------/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4773
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_MetaBox has a deprecated constructor in .../------/wp-content/plugins/amp-story/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 61
>
> Notice: Undefined index: amp in .../------/wp-content/plugins/amp-story/amp-story.php on line 50

- Above the error text:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in .../------/wp-content/themes/15zine/library/core.php on line 2696

I actually deactivated the AMP plugins but no change was seen. It could be of another issue but I'm suspecting that the Yoast plugin changed some things of the category structure, but not fully sure though.

```php
// Actual breadcrumb function call
<?php cb_breadcrumbs(); ?>
// Yoast breadcrumb code
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
}
?>
```

```php
// About the breadcrumbs function in core.php file
```

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_breadcrumbs' ) ) {

function cb_breadcrumbs() {

    echo cb_get_breadcrumbs();
}
```

}
if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_get_breadcrumbs' ) ) {

```
function cb_get_breadcrumbs() {

    if ( ot_get_option('cb_breadcrumbs', 'on') == 'off' ) {
        return;
    }

    $cb_breadcrumb = NULL;
    $cb_post_type = get_post_type();
    $cb_cpt = cb_get_custom_post_types();

    if ( is_page() ) {

        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) {
            return;
        }
    }


    $cb_breadcrumb = '<div class="cb-breadcrumbs">';
    $cb_icon = '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>';
    $cb_breadcrumb .= '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url() ) . '">' . __("Home", "cubell").'</a>' . $cb_icon;

    if ( is_date() ) {

        if ( is_day() ) {
            $cb_breadcrumb_output = get_the_date( 'F j, Y' );
        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            $cb_breadcrumb_output = single_month_title( ' ', false );
        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            $cb_breadcrumb_output = get_query_var( 'year' );
        }

         $cb_breadcrumb .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">' . $cb_breadcrumb_output . '</div>';
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $cb_tag_id = get_query_var('tag_id');

        $cb_breadcrumb .= '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_tag_link($cb_tag_id) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), single_tag_title( '', FALSE ) ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . single_tag_title( '', FALSE ) . '</span></a></div>';

    } elseif ( is_category() ) {

        $cb_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
        $cb_current_category = get_category( $cb_cat_id );

        if ( $cb_current_category->category_parent == '1' ) {

            $cb_breadcrumb .= '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cb_current_category->term_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $cb_current_category->name ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . $cb_current_category->name . '</span></a></div>';

        }

        // Line 2696 starts from here  
        // else 
        // {
        //
        //      $cb_breadcrumb .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cb_current_category->category_parent ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), get_the_category_by_ID( $cb_current_category->category_parent ) ) ) . '"><span itemprop="title">' . get_the_category_by_ID( $cb_current_category->category_parent ) . '</span></a></div>' . $cb_icon;
        //      $cb_breadcrumb .= '<div itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cb_current_category->term_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $cb_current_category->name ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . $cb_current_category->name . '</span></a></div>';
        //
        //  }

    } elseif ( function_exists('buddypress') && ( is_buddypress() ) )  {
        global $bp;
        $cb_bp_output = NULL;
        $cb_bp_current_component = bp_current_component();
        $cb_bp_current_action = bp_current_action();

        if ( ( $cb_bp_current_action != 'my-groups' ) && ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'groups' ) ) {

            $cb_bp_group = $bp->groups->current_group;

            if ( ! is_numeric( $cb_bp_group ) ) {
                $cb_bp_group_id = $cb_bp_group->id;
                $cb_bp_group_name = $cb_bp_group->name;
                $cb_bp_group_link = bp_get_group_permalink($cb_bp_group);
                $cb_bp_output = '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . trailingslashit( bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . bp_get_groups_root_slug() ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . __('Groups', 'cubell') . '</span></a></div>' . $cb_icon . $cb_bp_group_name;
            } else {
                $cb_bp_output =  __('Groups', 'cubell');
            }

            $cb_breadcrumb .=  $cb_bp_output;
        }

        if ( ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'activity' ) || ( $cb_bp_current_action == 'my-groups' ) || ( $cb_bp_current_action == 'public' ) || ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'settings' ) || ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'forums' ) || ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'friends' ) ) {

            if ( isset( $bp->activity->current_id ) ) {
                $cb_bp_activity = $bp->activity->current_id;
            } else {
                $cb_bp_activity = NULL;
            }

            $cb_activity_title = get_the_title();
            $cb_bp_activity_link = bp_get_members_directory_permalink();
            $cb_bp_output .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . esc_url( $cb_bp_activity_link ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . __('Members', 'cubell') . '</span></a></div>' . $cb_icon . $cb_activity_title;

            if ( $cb_bp_activity != NULL ) {

                $cb_bp_output .=  __('Members', 'cubell');
            }

            $cb_breadcrumb .=  $cb_bp_output;
        }

        if ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'messages' ) {

            $cb_breadcrumb .=  __('Messages', 'cubell');
        }

        if ( $cb_bp_current_component == 'register' ) {

            $cb_breadcrumb .=  __('Register', 'cubell');
        }

        if ( bp_is_directory() ) {
            $cb_breadcrumb = '<div>';
        }

    } elseif ( ( in_array( $cb_post_type, $cb_cpt ) == true ) || ( $cb_post_type == 'post' ) ) {

        $cb_categories =  get_the_category();

        if ( ! empty ( $cb_categories ) ) {

            if ( $cb_categories[0]->category_parent == '0' ) {

                $cb_breadcrumb .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_category_link($cb_categories[0]->term_id) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $cb_categories[0]->name ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . $cb_categories[0]->name.'</span></a></div>';

            } else {

                $cb_breadcrumb_output = '<a href="' . get_category_link($cb_categories[0]->category_parent) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), get_the_category_by_ID($cb_categories[0]->category_parent) ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . get_the_category_by_ID($cb_categories[0]->category_parent) . '</span></a>' . $cb_icon;

                $cb_breadcrumb_output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($cb_categories[0]->term_id) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $cb_categories[0]->name ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . $cb_categories[0]->name . '</span></a>';

                $cb_current_cat = get_category($cb_categories[0]->category_parent);

                if ( $cb_current_cat->category_parent != '0' ) {

                    $cb_breadcrumb_output = '<a href="' . get_category_link($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '</span></a>' . $cb_icon . $cb_breadcrumb_output;

                    $cb_current_cat = get_category( $cb_current_cat->category_parent );

                    if ( $cb_current_cat->category_parent != '0' ) {

                        $cb_breadcrumb_output = '<a href="' . get_category_link($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '</span></a>' . $cb_icon . $cb_breadcrumb_output;

                        $cb_current_cat = get_category( $cb_current_cat->category_parent );

                        if ( $cb_current_cat->category_parent != '0' ) {

                            $cb_breadcrumb_output = '<a href="' . get_category_link($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) ) ) . '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' . get_the_category_by_ID($cb_current_cat->category_parent) . '</span></a>' . $cb_icon . $cb_breadcrumb_output;
                        }
                    }

                }

                $cb_breadcrumb .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">' . $cb_breadcrumb_output . '</div>';

            }
        }

    } elseif ( is_page() ) {
        $cb_parent_page = get_post( $post->post_parent );

        $cb_parent_page_title = $cb_parent_page->post_title;
        $cb_breadcrumb .=  '<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="' . get_permalink( $cb_parent_page->ID ) . '"><span itemprop="title">' . $cb_parent_page_title . '</span></a></div>';
    }


    $cb_breadcrumb .= apply_filters( 'cb_breadcrumbs_output', '' );
    $cb_breadcrumb .= '</div>';


    return $cb_breadcrumb ;
}
```

}

As I explained and provided the background of the issue already, I expected to see the correct breadcrumb (which I saw) and also to make the categories pages working, but instead, I only see the header of the site off-centered and the error "The site is experiencing technical difficulties." under it. Most other pages are working fine as far as I checked, only the category pages have this issue. Even the admin panel is working normally.

Comment: The stuff from the AMP plugin is a notice and a deprecation warning only, those should not prevent the site from working. The recoverable fatal error however could be the culprit, and that comes from your theme. It appears to try and output some result there, but encounters an instance of WP_Error instead, and fails at that point.

Comment: May we see the query function/method call that specifies `is_author`?

Comment: @misorude It could be, but I'm not sure how to solve it (if that's the case). But whenever this kind of error shows, it would be a blank screen and the error message shows at the center, and also it affects the whole site and admin panel too. But now, as I described, the admin panel is working and also most of the site is working, only the category pages are affected and it shows the header too. Confused!

Comment: You need to figure out what the actual error is, currently that gets hidden from you by the other error. Check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/269841 for how to go out that.

Comment: @halfer I don't know from where to find that `is_author` code because it is a custom template, not a website that I wrote.

Comment: @misorude I added some code above about the fatal error (it is a code about the breadcrumb). I mentioned where Line 2696 is in the code. That else section was already commented. I'd appreciate if you try and check if the issue is actually from there.

Comment: Code that is commented out can not actually cause errors. Make sure there is no mismatch between how “lines” are counted on the server-side, and with whatever you are looking at the code client-side - could be due to FTP mode used when transferring the file, or the program you used to open it having problems with different OS line breaks, or something like that. The error is probably in the lines before that, the `get_category_link` call looks like a promising candidate. Put a `var_dump(get_category_link( $cb_current_category->term_id ));` before that line, and see what you get.

Comment: @misorude It's this: `string(53) "https://www.-----.com/advertising/"`. But now I'm checking it, and it seems to be working fine. It wasn't working for 2 days. Not sure how it started working and hope it won't happen again. Thanks a lot for your help. If it continues again, I'll write here again for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
if ( $cb_current_category->category_parent == '1' ) {
```

Change it to

```
if ( $cb_current_category->category_parent == '0' ) {
```

remove the else from the comment from line 2696. one of those things being appended is not a "string", but actually a WP_Error object.

It might Siteurl problem as well. the Siteurl option value in your WordPress database may not contain a valid entry

Run the following query to verify that the value is indeed incorrect

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
```

You will likely find a serialized array containing a WP_Error object.
Correct the option value by setting it with your domain’s URL.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '[YOUR URL]' WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
```

there might be malware has infected your installation. Be sure to run a scan on your server.

Comment: We actually got a WordPress developer to check the issue, he did some category structure fixes and it fixed the issue. It now works as usual. Thanks for the answer though.